# GWT:getting error in simple Hello Application

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I am running a basic GWT application in IntelliJ, below is my code

```
           public class test implements EntryPoint {

/**
 * This is the entry point method.
 */
public void onModuleLoad() {
    final Button button = new Button("Click me");
    final Label label = new Label();

    button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            if (label.getText().equals("")) {


                 testService.App.getInstance().getMessage("h", new AsyncCallback<Inter>() {
                     public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                         //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
                     }

                     public void onSuccess(Inter result) {
                        label.setText(result.getToken());
                     }
                 });
            } else {
                label.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
```

Impl Class

```
        public class testServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements testService {
// Implementation of sample interface method
public Inter getMessage(String msg) {
    RdbHelper rdbHelper = new RdbHelper();
    return rdbHelper.getMsg();

}
```

}

RdbHelper Class

```
    public class RdbHelper {

public Inter getMsg(){
    Inter inter = new Inter();
    return inter;
}
```

}

Inter Class

```
        public class Inter implements Serializable{

private String token ;

public String getToken() {
    token = "Hello";
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}
```

}

I should see msg  "Hello"  but i am getting this error .

```
       ERROR: Errors in 'file:/C:/work/Grails/TestFinal/src/com/test/client/test.java'. 
       ERROR: Unable to find type 'com.test.client.test'. 
       ERROR: Line 28: No source code is available for type com.test.shared.Inter; did  you forget to inherit a required module?. 
     ERROR: Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable. 
     ERROR: Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be   inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries   properly. 
     ERROR: Failed to load module 'test' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.75 Safari/535.7' at 127.0.0.1:51070.
```

Note: I am trying the same thing in Eclipse and its working fine, but this is the Issue i am facing in IntelliJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remember to put

```
<source path="shared"/>
```

in your Module.gwt.xml file.
You need to do this to compile the code in shared package to javascript code. If not it only compiles the code in the client package and thereby the code in the shared folder is not available on client side.